# Xamarin.Android não atualiza Resource.designer no C# Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Quando eu insiro um botão (por exemplo) na activity o arquivo `Resource.desigenr.cs` não atualiza para acrescentar o item `Botao` e os dados (como o id por exemplo) logo eu não consigo acessar o mesmo pelo comando `findViewbyId`.

Já procurei em todo lugar e fiz os poucos procedimentos que encontrei. O que me pareceu mais promissor foi o de entrar na pasta `values` dentro de `resources` e verificar se o arquivo `string.xml` estava apontando o diretório de compilação para o `AndroidResource`. Verifiquei isso e esta ok... Já também desinstalei o `xamarim` e instalei de novo pra ver se algum `path` teria vindo corrompido e também não funciona.

Comment: Mostre como você está fazendo

Answer (score 0):

Olá @Thiago Cordeiro,

Considerando a pouca informação que você forneceu, posso te sugerir as seguintes tentativas para verificar se seu problema se resolve.

1) Limpar o conteudo de Resource.designer (apagar), realizar a limpeza da solução e executar o build do projeto.

2) Certificar que você está inserindo os controles no local certo, pois os identificadores são gerados quando Resources(imagens, cores, strings, controles, etc) são adicionados ao projeto e estão agrupados pela sua natureza, logo certifique-se de que está procurando no local certo.

3) Certifique-se de que está definindo seu controles via Designer(xml) pois  caso seus identificadores foram definidos programaticamente (via código), não são gravados em Resources.designer

Para maiores informações não se esqueça de olhar a documentação oficial:

- [Do Google](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int))
- [Da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.activity.findviewbyid?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)